# Moving in RelativeLayout android

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I am making an app in which a `RelativeLayout` fits completely in the screen. I have than added a button which zooms in this layout using `setScaleX()` an `setScaleY()` to the layout. As a consequence (obviously) the whole layout does'nt fit in the screen anymore. So I first thought using a `ScrollView` to be able to move in the `RelativeLayout`, but this didn't work. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Here is the xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layoutMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="phou.minesweeper.GameActivity">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/chronometer"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewBest">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/grid"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"></RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The `RelativeLayout` which i'm zooming is the one with id = grid.
The xml code is so short because all of the views are created in java.

Comment: show me ur xml code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are manipulating the view size in Java using setScaleX/Y, you probably need to implement an onTouchListener on the RelativeLayout to handle drag motion events to allow you to move the entire layout programatically.

Assuming the view you are scaling is @id/grid, a simple OnTouchListener would look something like this.

```
final View grid = findViewById(R.id.grid);
final Point dispSize = new Point();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(dispSize);
grid.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    private PointF mAnchor = new PointF();
    private PointF mTouchPoint = new PointF();

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        mTouchPoint.set(motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY());
        switch (motionEvent.getActionMasked()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                mAnchor.set(mTouchPoint);
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                float dx = mTouchPoint.x - mAnchor.x;
                float dy = mTouchPoint.y - mAnchor.y;
                float left = grid.getX() + dx;
                float right = left + grid.getWidth();
                float top = grid.getY() + dy;
                float bottom = top + grid.getHeight();
                if (grid.getWidth() > dispSize.x) {
                    if (left > 0f) {
                        left = 0f;
                    }
                    if (right < dispSize.x) {
                        left += dispSize.x - right;
                    }
                }
                if (grid.getHeight() > dispSize.y) {
                    if (top > 0f) {
                        top = 0f;
                    }
                    if (bottom < dispSize.y) {
                        top += dispSize.y - bottom;
                    }
                }
                grid.setX(left);
                grid.setY(top);
                return true;
            default:
                return true;
        }
    }
});
```

Note that this OnTouchListener will only receive touch events that have NOT been intercepted by the content views of the RelativeLayout (which we don't see in the XML code). This means that the content views need to pass any unconsumed touch events up the hierarchy by returning false in their own touch/gesture listeners.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I still have a problem with this. There is no limit to how much it can move. I can drag the layout out of the screen. Do you have any solution for this? Thanks

Comment: The initial answer was just to give a flavour of what you can do in your onTouchListener.  I have edited the answer to show one simple way to keep the grid within screen limits.  Your specific requirements will probably need further refinements, but hopefully you get the idea.